# How can remove elements from array which elements are another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays which values are:

```
const allValues = ["111", "111", "111", "222", "111", "222"]

const removingValues = ["111", "111", "222"]
```

And I want this array.

```
const remaningValues = ["111", "222", "111"]
```

I have to tried `_.difference(allValues, removingValues)` but it given empty array. How can I do that in simple way?

the first array includes `"111" : 4 times` and `"222" : 2 times`
the removing values from this array are `"111" : 2 times` `"222" : 1 times`
and the remaining values should be : `"111" : 4-2 = 2` and `"222" : 2-1 = 1`

Comment: _but it given empty array_ what else do you expect? You want to remove `111` and `222` from the array containing all values. Do you see any other value in the `allValues` array that isn't in `removingValues` array?

Comment: I expect that `const remaningValues = ["111", "222", "111"]` @Yousaf

Comment: If you were doing it with simple code instead of looking for some in-built method, what would it look like?

Comment: The result you get is excepted behavior. Are there any rules you want to follow?

Comment: As a summary, I should remove elements from allValues array. The removing values are in removingValues array. And the result should be remaingValues array. @H.Pauwelyn

Comment: @Yousaf Yes I want to remove `"111"` and `"222"`. There are `4 x "111"` and `2 x "222"` in the array. I remove `2 x "111"` and `1 x "222"` from the array.

Comment: Yes but if you want hold the differences, you got an empty array. Because there are no differences. That's why I've ask for any other rules like only the elements in the same order.

Comment: The difference is the number of values in two arrays. @H.Pauwelyn I mean, the `_.difference` function shows true result.

Comment: Ah ok now I understand your question.

Comment: @H.Pauwelyn do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: no I don't have. Did you tried one of the answers?I don't answer if I got the same idea as anyone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in a very concise way with [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), [Array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) and [Array.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) like this:

```js
const vals = ["111", "111", "111", "222", "111", "222"]
const rms = ["111", "111", "222"]

let r = rms.reduce((r,c) => (r.splice(r.indexOf(c), 1) && r), [...vals])

console.log(r)
```

The idea is to start from the values to remove and in the Array.reduce put as a starting value for the accumulator an actual copy of the `allValues`. Then inside of the reduce just remove the values which match the `indexOf` via `Array.splice`

The copy of the `vals` is so that we do not `mutate` the original array. If you do not care about mutating that you can just have:

```
let r = rms.reduce((r,c) => (r.splice(r.indexOf(c), 1) && r), vals)
```

Comment: It's basic way. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You could use this function:

```js
const allValues = ["111", "111", "111", "222", "111", "222"];
const removingValues = ["111", "111", "222"];

const result = allValues.filter(s => {
    let i = removingValues.indexOf(s);
    return i > -1 && removingValues.splice(i, 1);
});

console.log(result);
```

The above has a time complexity of *O(n²)*, so if you are working with large arrays it will be better to create a hash of some sort, for example using a `Map`, which will give a *O(n)* time complexity:

```js
const allValues = ["111", "111", "111", "222", "111", "222"];
const removingValues = ["111", "111", "222"];

const map = new Map(removingValues.map(s => [s, 0]));
removingValues.forEach(s => map.set(s, map.get(s)+1));

const result = allValues.filter(s => {
    let i = map.get(s);
    return i && map.set(s, i-1);
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: It doesn't work in my local. When I add console.log(s) it gives me 111 and it can't find 111 in removingValues array because there is "111" not 111.

Comment: Then your question is incomplete. A string is not the same as a number.

Answer (score 1):

The order of your expected remaining values makes little sense to me.  If you are ok with `['111', '111', '222']` (instead of `['111', '222', '111']`), then this simple code should do it:

```js
const without = (i, xs) => i > -1 ? xs.slice(0, i).concat(xs.slice(i + 1)) : xs

const removeAll = (all, rems, idx = all .indexOf (rems[0])) => rems .length
  ? removeAll (without (idx, all), rems .slice(1))
  : all
  
const allValues = ["111", "111", "111", "222", "111", "222"];
const removingValues = ["111", "333", "111", "222"];

console .log (
  removeAll (allValues, removingValues)
)
```

The helper function `without` just return a copy of the old array with the given index not included.

`removeAll` is a simple recursion on the things to remove.  If it's empty, we return the remaining list.  Otherwise, we remove from our list the first index that matches the first element to remove, and pass that and the remaining items to match back into `removeAll`.

Comment: Thank you its helpful for me :)